# Extract tags from Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, html, regex, parsing, google-tag-manager

I'w writing and analyzer of web pages which search a fragment of codes on web pages. For example, with some regular expressions I can found if site uses Google Analytics or jquery and etc. But some site put these codes into Google Tag Manager so I cannot find them directly. Does anybody tried to extract them? Maybe it could been extracted from googletagmanager.com/gtm.js script, but I could not understand how.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a headless browser that renders the page's content and then analyze the content of the rendered page. An example of a headless browser you could use is [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)